# setting environment variable in Python from bash wrapper

Tags: python, bash, shell

I am trying to run Python script through a wrapper script which sets path to different directories and handle log file & script execution.

While running shell scripts through this wrapper we assign the paths by using ${temp_data_path} in the ksh&bash scripts ,so now I want the same path but in my python script.

I am trying below,as I believe i have to set environment variable first by reading the value set for temp_data_path by my wrapper:

```
os.environ[temp_data_path] = ??not sure how I can assign the value from wrapper here

print os.environ[temp_data_path]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what exactly you're asking. The name of your shell environment variable is `temp_data_path`, right?. Are you maybe just looking for `print  os.environ['temp_data_path']` inside Python? (Note the single quotes)

Comment: The wrapper script should set the environment variable, you don't need to assign it in the Python script as well.

Comment: Perfect @LukasGraf,it worked like a charm. os.environ["temp_data_path"] assigned the path set by wrapper.

Comment: Great, glad I could help. I therefore linked an appropriate duplicate, so that we can close the question.